# Semaphore not working as expected ,it is getting locked

Tags: multithreading, semaphore

i am using semaphore for thread communication i have two threads one is OddThread and another is EvenThread ,i am printing value from 1 to 10 OddThread will print only odd numbers between  1 to 10 and EvenThread thread is printing only even numbers between 1 to 10. for that i have used semaphore for threads to communicate properly .what is actually happening is that OddThread is printing only 1 and EvenThread only 2 and then both get stopped. I am  not under standing what is actually happening.can any body suggest.

```
   public class ThreadProducerConsumerSemaphore {


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore p = new Semaphore(1);
     Semaphore c = new Semaphore(0);
     OddThread producer = new OddThread(p, c);
     EvenThread consumer = new EvenThread(p, c);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(producer, "Thread producer");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(consumer, "Thread consumer");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}

 class OddThread implements Runnable {
Semaphore p;
Semaphore c;

public OddThread(Semaphore p, Semaphore c) {
    super();
    this.p = p;
    this.c = c;
}

int counter = 1;

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            p.acquire(1);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "
                    + counter);
            if (counter == 10) {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
            c.release(1);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
 }

  class EvenThread implements Runnable {
Semaphore p;
Semaphore c;
int counter = 2;

public EvenThread(Semaphore p, Semaphore c) {
    super();
    this.p = p;
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            c.acquire(1);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "
                    + counter);
            if (counter == 10) {
                break;
            }
            counter=counter+2;
            p.acquire(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can't be correct, it's not even symmetrical.

```
p.acquire(1);
c.release(1);

c.acquire(1);
p.acquire(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EvenThread.run` method acquires both `c` and `p`, rather than releasing one of them.

Note, however, that your code doesn't look like it'll exit properly even once it's been fixed. Consider: neither thread releases a semaphore before it exits, so one of the threads will inevitably be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem:

```
    ............
    c.acquire(1);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "
            + counter);
    if (counter == 10) {
        break;
    }
    counter=counter+2;
    p.acquire(1);   <--deadlock this has already been acquired by the other thread.
    ..............
```

you should release p here, to allow the other thread to continue; so replace the line I indicated with `p.release(1)` and it should be fine.